# Scrape the <p> tag using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have a requirement to extract the

tag from the HTML. However I am not able to get it done. 
This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="small-12 columns" id="gennedword-container">
    <p class="text-center" id="gennedword">
        Press "New Word"
    </p>
</div>
```

I tried using the following, but I dont get the text.

```python
word = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gennedword"]')
print(word.get_attribute('text'))
print(word.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

All it returns was `None` and for innerHtml I get -

```html
<img src="/wordgenerator/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="vertical-align:middle;">
```

Comment: what is your requirement from the innerHtml ??

Comment: clearly *word.get_attribute('text')* wont work for anchor tags

Comment: I want to extract - Press "New Word"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.
Added a sleep for 1 sec and the text appeared.

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question you are trying to scrape the `<p>` tag and extract the text `Press "New Word"`. To achieve that you can use the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gennedword-container' and @class='small-12 columns']/p[@id='gennedword' and @class='text-center']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code. But it returns the following <img src="/wordgenerator/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="vertical-align:middle;">

Comment: it will not return "new word" becuase somehow... **gennedword** id is not pointing to the element

Comment: i guess there are multiple element with same ID

Comment: Is there a way to get this done. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: could you do a **$("#gennedword")** in the console of inspector...and see for yourself how many elements it is returning..

Comment: I just checked. There is only element for the ID

Comment: I get an error from the Inspect Element console- $ is not a function

Comment: I get the same answer.

Comment: That means the `xpath` is not unique so you need to provide some more of the outerHTML and update the Question till we get some unique `id` or `class` attribute.

Comment: We require the outerHTML possibly till the node which contains `<img src="/wordgenerator/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="vertical-align:middle;">` atleast.